# Remove path from Python exceptions

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a very long path and thus errors from Python become very long, since the path is always printed like:

```
[Finished in 31.3s with exit code 4294967295]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\work\test.py"]
[dir: C:\work\]
[path: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4; ..............]
```

Is there any way to change this behaviour (e.g. by changing the Python source code) to not print the path?

Comment: Python doesn't do that, your IDE does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output is not produced by Python. It is produced by the Sublime build command.

Simply not run your code under Sublime, or [customise the `exec.py` script](https://superuser.com/questions/617511/sublime-text-do-not-print-path-of-build-command) to remove the debug it adds after running your script.